# Oracle primary key generator in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, primary-key

My app allows users to create an account (stored in database) and place orders.
When a client registers himself, I want to generate a primary key named **CLIENT_CODE** to identify him, starting from x value and increment it with y value. (I'm using oracle 11g atm)
I've tried this so far:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String fname = jTextField9.getText();
        String lname = jTextField10.getText();
        String city = jTextField11.getText();
        String street = jTextField13.getText();
        String number = jTextField14.getText();
        String userClient = jTextField15.getText();
        String pass1 = String.valueOf(jPasswordField5.getPassword());
        String pass2 = String.valueOf(jPasswordField6.getPassword());

        if(verifyFields()){
            if(!checkUsername(userClient)){
                OraclePreparedStatement ps;
                OracleResultSet rs;
                String registerClient = "insert into CLIENT (FNAME_CL, LNAME, CITY, STREET, NUMBER, MONEY, CLIENT_CODE, USER_CLIENT, PASS) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                try {
                    ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) JavaConnectDb.ConnectDb().prepareStatement(registerClient);
                    ps.setString(1, fname);
                    ps.setString(2, lname);
                    ps.setString(3, city);
                    ps.setString(4, street);
                    ps.setString(5, number);
                    ps.setDouble(6, 0.0);
                    ps.setInt(7, ???); <--- here should be the generated primary key
                    ps.setString(8, userClient);
                    ps.setString(9, pass1);

                    if(ps.executeUpdate() != 0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account created!");
                    } else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Check your info");
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start your Client database entry with a **CLIENT_CODE** of ***x*** then on any future Client entries, merely retrieve the **CLIENT_CODE** used in the **last** (previous) database entry and increment it by ***y***.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Don't do that; if two entries are made (nearly) simultaneously then they will both request the latest `CLIENT_CODE` and will both try to set the same value. You need a way to atomically generate unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it in Java; handle the primary key value creation in the database using a [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_6015.htm):

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE CLIENT__CLIENT_CODE__SEQ
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
```

Then just use your sequence in the `INSERT` statement and use the [`RETURNING` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#i2122356) to get the generated value as an `OUT` parameter of your prepared statement.

```sql
insert into CLIENT (
  FNAME_CL,
  LNAME,
  CITY,
  STREET,
  NUMBER,
  MONEY,
  CLIENT_CODE,
  USER_CLIENT,
  PASS
) values (
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  ?,
  CLIENT__CLIENT_CODE__SEQ.NEXTVAL,
  ?,
  ?
) RETURNING CLIENT_CODE INTO ?
```

If you were using Oracle 12c then you could use [`GENERATED AS IDENTITY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) in the table's `CREATE` DDL statement to generate the values without creating a separate sequence.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much!